# C creating a String Stuct

Tags: c, string, struct, segmentation-fault

So, I've been working on implementing this struct for a String. However, I keep on getting a Segmentation Fault when calling *createString();

Here us the .h contents

```
typedef struct {
    char *characters;
    int length;
} String;

String *createString();
```

Here is the implementation in my .c file

```
String *createString(){
    char *m,b;
    int n = 0;
    String *theS = (String *) malloc (sizeof(String));
    m = theS->characters;
    b = getchar();
    while((b = getchar()) != '\n'){
        *(m+n) = b;
        n++;
        m = realloc(m, n+1);
    }
    *(m+n) = '\0';
    theS->length = strlen(theS->characters);
    return new;
}
```

Comment: 99% failed bacause of `m = theS->characters`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, what is wrong with that line?

Comment: You don't find it a little odd you're storing a character in a buffer that has no actual allocation assigned to it yet? Your first loop iteration dereferences `*(m+0)`, where `m` is an indeterminate pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Clearly a problem, though things have gone sideways before it gets that far.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I miss typed that it should be theS

Comment: And remember to use `void` since your function as has no arguments: `String *createString(void)`

Comment: you are dereferencing a 'random' address in the later code. that will definitely cause a segfault.

Comment: Nor do I see any reason this function has to dynamically allocate a `String`. The internal `characters` buffer clearly should be dynamically managed, but if you *really* think about it, a simple by-value structure return of `String` is *very* likely sufficient.  The additional indirection just muddies the waters. Oh, and `length` should be an *unsigned* type unless you can possibly justify a potential *negative* length of a string. I certainly can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1

**Q**: after this line:

```
String *theS = (String *) malloc (sizeof(String));
```

what does `theS->characters` point to?

**A**: Who knows? Nowhere useful, though.

You'll need to allocate at least a character, to hold the `'\0'` that eventually gets inserted.

```
String *theS = malloc (sizeof(String));
theS->characters = malloc(1);
```

#### Problem 2

You then modify `m` all over the place, but never reassign that value to `theS->characters`, so when you say

```
theS->length = strlen(theS->characters);
```

that's not going to be a very helpful answer.

Right before that line, add:

```
theS->characters = m;
```

#### Problem 3

```
return new;
```

should probably be:

```
return theS;
```

#### Problem 4

You're throwing away the first character. Just remove the standalone `b = getchar();` line.

#### Working example:

https://ideone.com/tm1TG9

Comment: I made all of the changes and it is working! Except for one thing. When I print out theS->characters, all the characters except the first one are outputted

Comment: Note "Problem 4", and double-check against the working version in the link.

Answer (score 2):

As @HuStmpHrr suggests: when you allocate your `String`, you don't allocate any space for its `characters` field to point to, so when you try to access what it points to, things will go bad.

Answer (score 0):

Using your style and not checking allocation errors:

```
String *createString(){
    int n = 0;
    char *m = malloc(1);
    int c;
    String *theS = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        m = realloc(m, n + 2);
        m[n] = c;
        n++;
    }
    m[n] = '\0';
    theS->characters = m;
    theS->length = n;
    return theS;
}
```

Comment: Notice how `getchar` returns an int that should be checked for EOF.